# How to fetch number of same values in PDO, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my mysql structure is like

```
ID  color   user
1   red      A
2   red      B
3   green    C
4   red      D
5   white    C
```

and so on;

First, I need to get number of SAME values. For example I should calculate (take a look the db structure) 3 for red (there are 3 times red), 1 for green and 1 for white.

Then I need to get the highest calculated number (It should be 3 for the db because there are 3 times red , the others are 1)

My db connection is

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=colors', $user, $pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_color ORDER BY ID";
    $get = $db->prepare($query);
    $get->execute();

    foreach ($get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

       No idea ...

    }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

I don't have any idea how I can do that. I will be waiting the answers, thank you for reading.

Comment: Of same value: use a `WHERE` clause. Highest values: use `MAX()` in conjunction with a `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` and `order by` and `limit`:

```
select count(*)
from user_color
group by color
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I hadn't thought  sql side :) Thanks!!